# Excel VBA input box letters only and max length

Tags: vba, excel

I want an input-box that only allows 1-3 characters in length and only letters A-Z. I've tried a few different ways but cant seem to get anything to work

I am using this code now but it only restricts length

```
Sub Change_Ticket_Initials()

Dim strReturn As String

strReturn = InputBox("Enter Initials", "Change Ticket Initials")
If strReturn = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'if "" exit sub

If Len(strReturn) < 1 Or Len(strReturn) > 3 Then
    MsgBox "Must Be 1-3 Characters Try Again"
    Run "Change_Ticket_Initials"
Else
    Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2").Value = UCase(strReturn)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is exactly that you want? To check the input as the user presses a key or only when the cell loses focus (e.g. upon ENTER key)?

Comment: @FDavidov When the user clicks Ok if the input box is anything but letters then a msgbox pops up saying letters only and then reopens the input box

Comment: try using `RegEx`

Comment: As suggested by others, you can use Regular expressions or a solution as posted by @Alex below (with the required fix for lowercase input). I personally prefer explicit coding (e.g. check if each letter is found in the string `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`). It is a matter of taste in fact.

Comment: @luke have you tried my solution below using `RegEx` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
Sub Change_Ticket_Initials()

    Dim strReturn As String

    Do
        strReturn = UCase$(InputBox("Enter Initials", "Change Ticket Initials"))

        Select Case True
            Case strReturn = ""
                 Exit Sub
            Case strReturn Like "[A-Z]", _
                 strReturn Like "[A-Z][A-Z]", _
                 strReturn Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"

                 Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2").Value = strReturn
                 Exit Do
            Case Else
                 MsgBox "Must Be 1-3 Characters Try Again"
        End Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What about lowercase?

Comment: This accepts any case letters and always writes upper case as in the OPs current code.

Comment: You are converting the input to uppercase (`UCase$`) which might not be what the OP wants. The simplest solution is to use the conversion for the verification only. That would do the job while maintaining the input as-is.

Comment: Personally I don't think he would want to reject "aaa" because its not "AAA".  He wants uppercase to be written as thats what he currently uses.

Comment: I didn't mean rejection of "aaa". What I meant is accept (and perhaps store) whatever the user enters AS-IS, and as long as it contains 3 characters. Anyway, it looks that your answer is what he/she was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly why they came up with `RegEx` object.

You can check for characters that are A-Z (or a-z) by entering in the `RegEx.Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]"`
.
You can expand it to allow a size of 1-3 characters, by adding `.Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{1,3}"`.

Thanks to @Slai , need to add `^` and `$` at the begining and the end to close it.

**Code**

```
Sub Change_Ticket_Initials()

Dim strReturn As String
Dim RegEx As Object, Match As Object

strReturn = InputBox("Enter Initials", "Change Ticket Initials")

Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegEx
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$" ' <-- does it all in 1 line : Match 1-3 consecutive letters
End With

Set Match = RegEx.Execute(strReturn)

If Match.Count = 1 Then ' <-- make sure there is only 1 match
    Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2").Value = UCase(strReturn)
Else
    MsgBox "Must Be 1-3 Characters Try Again"
    Run "Change_Ticket_Initials"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The anchors are needed `^[A-Za-z]{1,3}$` because `AAAA` is 1 match. Setting any of the RegEx flags seems pointless in this case, but I like the recursive approach.

Comment: This works on the 1st attempt but if you enter numbers on the 2nd attempt it accepts it.

Comment: did you try this code ? "AAAA" is not a match, only 1-3, and if you more than 1 it's rejected in `If Match.Count = 1 Then `

Comment: I'll check it in few minutes

Comment: Ah my bad .. but `aaa1` is 1 match

Comment: @ShaiRado Also if i enter letters and numbers in the input box it will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you may be after this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Change_Ticket_Initials()
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim Control_Sheet_VB As Worksheet

    Do
        strReturn = UCase(Application.InputBox("Enter Initials", "Change Ticket Initials", Type:=2))
        If strReturn = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'if "" exit sub
        If strReturn Like "[A-Z]" Or strReturn Like "[A-Z][A-Z]" Or strReturn Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]" Then Exit Do
        MsgBox "Must Be 1-3 Characters" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Try Again"
    Loop
    Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2").Value = strReturn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to easily check if string contains only alphabets

```
Public Function CheckIfAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    CheckIfAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[A-ZA-Z]", Len(strValue))
End Function
```

And the whole implementation would be like combined with your if conditions:

```
Sub Change_Ticket_Initials()

Dim strReturn As String
strReturn = InputBox("Enter Initials", "Change Ticket Initials")

    If strReturn = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'if "" exit sub

If Len(strReturn) < 1 Or Len(strReturn) > 3 Or Not CheckIfAlpha(strReturn) Then
MsgBox "Must Be 1-3 Alphabet Characters Try Again"
Run "Change_Ticket_Initials"

    Else
Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2").Value = UCase(strReturn)
    End If

End Sub
Public Function CheckIfAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    CheckIfAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[A-ZA-Z]", Len(strValue))
End Function
```

PS: Tried and tested code :)

Answer (score 0):

I like this code, it checks if there are numbers in the input, you can try it:

```
Private Sub Change_Ticket_Initials()

Dim strReturn As String
Dim strCheck as Boolean
Dim aChar As Boolean

strReturn = InputBox("Enter Initials", "Change Ticket Initials")

For strCheck = 1 To Len(strReturn)
    aChar = False
    aChar = IsNumeric(Mid(strReturn, strCheck, 1))

    If aChar = True Then
        MsgBox "No numbers allowed"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next strCheck

If strReturn = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'if "" exit sub

If Len(strReturn) < 1 Or Len(strReturn) > 3 Then
    MsgBox "Must Be 1-3 Characters Try Again"
    Run "Change_Ticket_Initials"

Else
    Control_Sheet_VB.Range("C2").Value = UCase(strReturn)
End If

End Sub
```